# Is it possible to reconnect a websocket to a different host?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

Using socket.io, I have:

```
var socket = io.connect('//' + Server_Hostname, {secure: true});
```

If the server disconnects I want to try reconnecting to a different server. Is this possible without creating a new socket object via `io.connect` (and thus having to re-connect all my event handlers)?

Comment: Can't you just factor out the code which attaches the handlers into a function which accepts a socket? Then it would be easy to re-attach.

Comment: @TravisJ: yes, that's the other option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally know of no simple ways to do what you want, but to make things less complicated, you could save the listeners of the old socket, connect elsewhere, then transfer the old listeners.

```
socket.disconnect();
var listeners = socket.$events;
```

After we've stored the listeners of the previous socket, we can reconnect in two ways.

```
socket = io.connect(host, {
  'force new connection': true
});

//alternate reconnect method
socket.socket.connect(host);
```

We can then reassign the old listeners object.

```
socket.$events = listeners;
```

You then do have a new socket object, but reconnecting the event handlers with this method isn't too messy.

Comment: Thanks, `socket.socket.connect()` is the method I was looking for!

Comment: It turns out I have to also set `socket.socket.options.host = new_host` otherwise `socket.socket.connect(new_host)` just reconnects to the old host! (tested this in firefox and Chrome)

Comment: I'll investigate that, I was sure it accepted the host as an argument when I was testing, will post back with results.

Comment: It does accept the hostname as an argument, but it seemed to ignore it.